# Open/hide div that is already open by clicking link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have made a nav that opens when you click at the .products link and closes if you click anywhere on the screen. But it seems that if you click on the .product link when it is already open, it will not close. How can I do this?

```
$('#subnav').hide();

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('.products').length ) {
        $("#subnav").show();
    }else if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#subnav').length ) {
        $('#subnav').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: could you post your code too. Best way to display using [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Lg8ygxvr/)**

js

```
$("#subnav").hide();

$(".products").click(function (e) { //the usual behavior on click on .prducts
    $("#subnav").toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#subnav").click(function (e) { //ensures the #subnav will not hide on click on it
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function () { //ensures the #subnav will hide on click on document
    $("#subnav").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a click event on the document to hide the block and a click event on the button to show the block. And in the event of the button, you need to stop the propagation of the document's event.

Like that :

```
$("div").hide();

$("button").bind("click",function(e){        
    e.stopPropagation();    
    $("div").toggle(200);
});

$(document).bind("click",function(){
    $("div").hide(200);
});
```

Assuming your code looks like that :

```
<div></div>
<button>open</button>
```

See example : http://jsfiddle.net/oqgpceod/1/

Aditionnaly you may add this code to prevent the block from hiding when you click on it :

```
$("div").bind("click",function(e){        
    e.stopPropagation();    
});
```

Comment: @MaryMelody sorry little mistake, I've updated the link

Comment: if we click on div, it gets hidden, I think you need to apply `.stopPropagation()` on div click as well as it gets the document click functionality.

Comment: @4dgaurav It wasn't specifically asked in the question but indeed that makes more sense for the user experience

Comment: yeah.. btw I liked binding the click in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r2h57jhu/

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#subnav').hide();
    $(document).click(function(e) {                    
       $('#subnav:visible').hide();        
    });    


    $('.products').click( function (e) {        
        $('#subnav:not(:visible)').show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: It's cause when user click everywhere, the `subnav` do toggle !!

Comment: It's not what is asked. The block should **close** if you click elsewhere